# Getting globbing to work with `locate`?

Tags: wildcards, locate

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04, where I have:

```
$ locate --version
mlocate 0.23.1 [...]
```

The `man locate` page says:

> If --regex is not specified, PATTERNs can contain globbing  characters.   If  any  PATTERN
>   contains no globbing characters, locate behaves as if the pattern were *PATTERN*.

OK, so to do a little test: first, just searching for 'lua' works - but returns a ton (500+) of results:

```
$ locate 'lua' | head -5
/boot/grub/hwmatch.lua
/etc/alternatives/lua-compiler
/etc/alternatives/lua-compiler-manual
/etc/alternatives/lua-interpreter
/etc/alternatives/lua-manual

$ locate 'lua' | wc -l
560
```

I want to search for `.so` files with `lua` in the filename, so I try this as an attempt to use a globbing pattern:

```
$ locate 'lua*so*'
```

Nothing, 0 results. So I'm trying with a regex:

```
$ locate --regex 'lua.*so.*' | head -5
/usr/lib/libipelua.so.7.0.10
/usr/lib/liblua5.1.so
/usr/lib/liblua5.1.so.0
/usr/lib/liblua5.1.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libluaengine.so
```

Well, this works - so it is good enough.

But what puzzles me is this - if the man page says globbing is supported when not using regex, how should I format my glob pattern to have it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your glob will only match if the name starts with `lua`. Try this glob:

```
locate '*lua*so*'
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @PM2Ring - I guess when I saw that the `--regex` worked without a starting `*`, I expected the glob would too, but that wasn't correct. Your glob works just fine - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: No worries. Yeah, the regex matches if a substring of the data matches your regex pattern, unless you explicitly use the `^` start of line anchor in your regex. But a glob has to match the whole thing.

Comment: I guess it should be mentioned for future readers of this question that if you _don't_ quote the glob pattern (either with single or double quotes) then the shell itself will expand the glob to match files in the current directory and pass all those filenames to `locate`; this is generally **not** what you want here. :)

Comment: That feels almost like a bug to me... at least in the man page. Ok, theoretically, it's correctly documented - but this is not about a math paper. It needs to be practically correct. (The default matching can not be changed, of course - to fix it in the code would need a new option - does not sound sensible. But it's worth adding a line to the man page.) [note to self: report as bug]